# Index out of Range exception when using firebase database and storage to download data

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage, asyncdisplaykit

Here is my method to retrieve an array of user and post objects from the database.

```
func getRecentPost(start timestamp: Int? = nil, limit: UInt, completionHandler: @escaping ([(Post, UserObject)]) -> Void) {

    var feedQuery = REF_POSTS.queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp")
    if let latestPostTimestamp = timestamp, latestPostTimestamp > 0 {
        feedQuery = feedQuery.queryStarting(atValue: latestPostTimestamp + 1, childKey: "timestamp").queryLimited(toLast: limit)
    } else {
        feedQuery = feedQuery.queryLimited(toLast: limit)
    }

    // Call Firebase API to retrieve the latest records
    feedQuery.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let items = snapshot.children.allObjects

        let myGroup = DispatchGroup()

        var results: [(post: Post, user: UserObject)] = []

        for (index, item) in (items as! [DataSnapshot]).enumerated() {
            myGroup.enter()
            Api.Post.observePost(withId: item.key, completion: { (post) in
                Api.User.observeUser(withId: post.uid!, completion: { (user) in
                    results.insert((post, user), at: index) //here is where I get my error -> Array index is out of range
                    myGroup.leave()
                })
            })
        }
        myGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
            results.sort(by: {$0.0.timestamp! > $1.0.timestamp! })
            completionHandler(results)
        }
    })

}
```

Here is the call to the method from my view controller. I am currently using texture UI to help with a faster smoother UI.

```
var firstFetch = true
func fetchNewBatchWithContext(_ context: ASBatchContext?) {
    if firstFetch {
        firstFetch = false
        isLoadingPost = true
        print("Begin First Fetch")
        Api.Post.getRecentPost(start: posts.first?.timestamp, limit: 8  ) { (results) in
            if results.count > 0 {
                results.forEach({ (result) in
                    posts.append(result.0)
                    users.append(result.1)
                })
            }
            self.addRowsIntoTableNode(newPhotoCount: results.count)
            print("First Batch Fetched")
            context?.completeBatchFetching(true)
            isLoadingPost = false
            print("First Batch", isLoadingPost)
        }

    } else {
        guard !isLoadingPost else {
            context?.completeBatchFetching(true)
            return
        }
        isLoadingPost = true

        guard let lastPostTimestamp = posts.last?.timestamp else {
            isLoadingPost = false
            return
        }
        Api.Post.getOldPost(start: lastPostTimestamp, limit: 9) { (results) in
            if results.count == 0 {
                return
            }
            for result in results {
                posts.append(result.0)
                users.append(result.1)
            }
            self.addRowsIntoTableNode(newPhotoCount: results.count)
            context?.completeBatchFetching(true)
            isLoadingPost = false
            print("Next Batch", isLoadingPost)

        }
    }


}
```

In the first section of code, I have debugged to see if I could figure out what is happening. Currently, firebase is returning the correct number of objects that I have limited my query to (8). But, where I have highlighted the error occurring at, the index jumps when it is about to insert the fifth object, index[3] -> 4th object is in array, to index[7]-> 5th object about to be parsed and inserted, when parsing the 5th object.

So instead of going from index[3] to index[4] it jumps to index[7].
Can someone help me understand what is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The for loop has continued on its thread while the `observeUser` & `observePost` callbacks are on other threads. Looking at your code, you can probably just get away with `appending` the object to the `results` array instead of `inserting`. This makes sense because you are sorting after the for loop anyway, so why does the order matter?

Comment: Thanks that solved it for the time being. Do you think I could run into any problems in the future?

Comment: It shouldn't. But keep in mind that those `Api.Post.observePost` and `observeUser` methods calling your closures on separate threads than the thread the `for` loop is in--- in other words, your index value is likely to be different than when you made than call.